# Who defines the new operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is this program supposed to compile?

```
int main(){
    double* p = new double[4];
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

(It does compile with GCC 7.1.1)

The reason I ask this is because, I am not sure who is providing the definition of the `operator new`. 
Is it the language? is the compiler by default `#include`ing `<new>`?

To make this question more clear I can actually define (overwrite?) operator `new`.

```
#include<cstdlib> // malloc and size_t
#include<cassert> // assert
void* operator new[](unsigned long int sz){ // what if this is not defined? who provides `new`?
    assert(0); // just to check I am calling this function
    return std::malloc(sz);
}
int main(){
    double* p = new double[4]; // calls the new function above
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing here?

overriding `new`? overloading `new`? Is the definition of `new` special (magic) for the compiler? (e.g. if not defined use a language provided one).
What is the role of `#include<new>` in all this?

Comment: BTW, `delete p;` invokes UB. It should be `delete [] p;` Please know the basics first!

Comment: Who defines the `+` operator when you do `1+2`?

Comment: `operator new` is defined in the global namespace. Your compiler provides the implementation details (hence compatibly issues across shared libraries). I believe the language is defined by a governing board and compilers provide the implementation; this is why it takes time for features to be adopted... and some are never adopted.

Comment: @immibis I think here it's a bit different. `+` is part of the language for basic types, it's not an operator that can be overloaded for those types. In contrast, I believe `operator new` is implicitly declared in each translation unit and not part of the language per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a `new` expression, which invokes indeed `operator new[]`

```
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count );
```

The compiler is implicitly declaring the basic `operator new`s in each translation unit (this is specified by the standard), see the [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements).

> *The versions (1-4) are implicitly declared in each translation unit even if the < new> header is not included.*

In your second code snippet, you are **overloading** (technically you are actually **replacing**) `operator new` (not *overriding*, that's only for virtual functions), although you should overload `operator new[]` instead (note that if you don't, then `operator new[]` will fall back on `operator new`, so technically I believe your code is OK, but I'd just overload the array version for clarity).

Comment: Ok, I will change that to make the question more clear.

Comment: If I am overloading is with respect to what other version (other argument type)?

Comment: What if one is in system with no dynamic memory. (If such thing makes sense), what would the system provided new would do?

Comment: @alfC Technically you are **replacing** operator new, although most literature call this *overloading operator new*. In a system without dynamic memory, my guess is that `new` will work with some kind of memory pool preallocated on the stack, similar to how you'd do a placement new.

Comment: And the automatic compiler provided the same as if `#include<new>`?

Comment: @alfC The standard only specifies that `operator new` is implicitly declared, but it's up to the implementation to decide how to implement it.

Comment: This also means that one has to replace operator delete together with new otherwise one wouldn't have the slightest idea if the delete operation corresponds to the new operation.

Comment: @alfC Yes indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There can be other overloads of operator new.  You have scalar and array versions both provided by the compiler, possibly by the standard library, and possibly by user-code.

There are additional overloads of new (and delete) if you write them yourself (if they don't have the signature of the built-in versions) or if you #include new.  If you provide operators that match the builtin signatures, then they will replace the builtin version.  Beware.  :)

The main reasons people include  are for

1) constructing objects in a user-provided memory address

2) non-throwing versions of new

There are, of course, operator delete overloads as well, since new/delete must be overloaded pairwise to work together, or nearly certain destruction will follow.  If your operator new matches the built-in signature, it will replace rather than overload the built-in version.

Remember, a "new expression" as simple as:

```
std::string myString = new std::string();
```

really works in 2 parts:  1) Allocating memory (via operator new), and then, 2) constructing an object in that memory.  If successful, it returns the pointer to that object, and if failure, cleans up what was constructed, deallocates whatever was allocated, and then throws.

When you overload operator new, you are only dealing with the memory allocation, not the constructor call, and the object will be constructed in whatever address this operator returns.  For the normal placement new, you might see code like this:

```
char myBuffer[1024];  // assume aligned; nobody needs more than 1024 bytes
std::string *ptr = new (myBuffer) std::string();
assert (ptr == &myBuffer);
```

The extra parameter to new is the myBuffer address, which is immediately returned by operator new and becomes the place where the object is constructed.  The assertion should pass, and shows that the string was created *in the bytes of myBuffer*.

The no-throw versions of new are also available after #including new, which also uses an extra argument to the operator:

```
char * buf = new (std::nothrow) char[MAX_INT];
if (buf) {
    std::cout << "WHOA, you have a lot of memory!!!\n";
}
```

Now instead of failing, it'll return a null pointer, so you have to check it.

Comment: So in my case I am replacing a default definition, not overloading. No? If so, that is unique of new, no other function behaves that way (?).

Comment: Basically yes.  I think you could argue about the generated members of classes (default constructors, assignment operators, etc.) which will be provided unless the user provides them or does something to prevent them.  Other operators only work on user defined types so we can't mess with the builtin math, etc.